# Checking for backedges in an LLVM pass

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, llvm, clang

I am writing an LLVM pass that modifies the intermediate code. I want to check each terminating instruction of a basic block to see if it has a back edge. To make it more clear, in the following example, I want to see if to reach labels `land.lhs.true` or `if.end`, a back jump is required.

```
entry:
  %pa = alloca %struct.Vertex, align 4
  .........
  br i1 %cmp, label %land.lhs.true, label %if.end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by back edge or back jump here, as LLVM intermediate code has no explicit layout in memory. You should think of basic blocks within each function has having no explicit order and no explicit assignment to memory addresses. This is handled by the backend when emitting assembly code.